# What is this "cross" in The Peace War?

Tags: the-peace-war

From page 64 of *The Peace War*:

> Quiller shrugged, started to speak, seemed to think better of it—then finally burst out with, "Allison, you know that... cross near the edge of the crater?" She nodded. "It was old, the stuff carved on it was badly weathered, but I could see... It had your name on it and... and today's date." Just the one cross, and just the one name. For a long while they were silent.

How could  the cross be inside the bobble as if she died for the outer world?

Comment: Did you see my comment on your last question?

Comment: It is mentioned very briefly in the text in a place where the reader (and character) are distracted. You probably read right past it. And you could deduce it from the relationships of the characters and their understanding of how bobbles work.

Comment: So outside the bubble they thought was an acident and she died ,and people put a cross on her honor ,on the same area of the crash and and at same time the plane blasted on the bubble and the cross somehow got inside?

Comment: They crashed into the bobble? No? And the plane dragged the cross inside while entering the bobble..

Comment: I did not understood if the Cross which Quiller saw was inside or outside the bubble?

Comment: The other answers states that it was a memorial that was erected outside the bubble, to memorialise the woman inside who was presumed to be dead (since the bubble was otherwise impenetrable).

Comment: So the man saw the Cross outside the bubble but he was inside it

Comment: He was inside of it until the bubble 'popped' and then he was outside of it and saw the cross.

Comment: Keep in mind, if he was inside the bubble, and it was outside, and it was still a bubble, he couldn't see ANYTHING, time would be completely stopped.  From his perspective, there was no bubble, the world changed in an instant, and there was suddenly a crater below him and a really old cross on the edge of the crater with today's date.

Answer (score 9):

### A memorial to Allison

The bobbles work to stop time, although they were initially thought to be impenetrable forcefields. Allison had been bobbled in order to stop her from exposing the plans of the group that later became the Peace Authority:

> She had been looking forward to her date with Paul Hoehler, if only to
> enjoy the expression on his face when she told him that the results of
> her test were secret. He had been so sure his bosses were up to
> something sinister at Livermore. **She now saw that Paul might be right;
> there was something going on at Livermore**.
>
> —*The Peace War*

That "something," of course, was the development of bobble technology:

> And she had detected other things—probe-opaque spheres below
> ground in the vicinity of the reactor.
>
> —*The Peace War*

The bobbles pause time inside them.
As such, when the bobble expires (after quite some time had passed), she believes it still to be the same day. However, to the world at large, that was the day she died. The cross is weathered because it has been sitting there (*outside* the bobble) for 50 years (give or take).

Comment: And the cross was almost certainly erected by Paul Hoehler, who was in love with Allison when she was bobbled.

Comment: So Quiller could see the Cross which was outside the bubble?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley - As I read it, the cross wasn’t inside the bobble: it was right outside of it (“near the edge of the crater.”).